# Tezos Baking Bonds Reduction

Tags: baking, governance

I have been baking Tezos for a few months and I have ran into a problem.

The bonds for endorsing, and baking, are too high.

I am now over delegated and I expect my baker is going to have a fully locked balance in about a month.

I would like to make a code change proposal for Tezos.

Can someone point me to the piece of code that defines the Baking Bonds amount?

I am guessing that the code changes needed to make bonds reduced by 50% are in multiple places.

I want endorsements to be 32xtz, and baking blocks bonds to be 256. Currently it's 64, and 512.

This would make it so my baker can double it's capacity.

This would be good for decentralization as smaller bakers like myself would be able to have more rolls. And new bakers will have an easier time getting started.

The transaction fees have been reduced many times, but baking bond costs have not. It's not really fair to the bakers now.

If any developers want to work on this with me let me know.

We have 11 days to make the code proposal to get into Grenada.

I have backing for this proposal from several other bakers already.

We just need a few good devs to help us with the code changes.

I would like to use my baker to inject the Proposal into the network.

I currently have 18 rolls.

I am going to download the gitlab source for Tezos and begin searching for all the needed code changes.

Comment: I found the changes I need to make to the protocols .ml files.

Comment: Next step would be to start a new protocol network with the source code I will make to get the protocol hash to submit the proposal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entire post belongs on Agora or Reddit as stackexchange is a place for asking technical questions, which this is not.

> I am now over delegated

Every baker deals with this. You are not unique in this regard.

> code changes needed to make bonds reduced by 50%

In my opinion, you should instead focus on adding an on/off switch that would allow bakers to turn on/off accepting delegations. This way, if you are near overdelgation, you can simply "turn off" new delegations.

Another possibility would be to lock the number of rolls a baker can have. For example, I have enough bond for 100 rolls, but if I wish, I could tell the protocol to never give me more than 90 rolls. That way, I always have enough bond and could never become over-delegated.

Dune.network, which is a fork of Tezos (same codebase) successfully implemented both of these options so the code work is practically done if you are looking for something far more beneficial to bring to Tezos than to simply change some parameters which may have FAR FURTHER reaching consequences than you may realize.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already posted on Agora but my post hasn't been approved yet.

Comment: I still want to learn how to make a protocol proposal. I used some of the scripts that are in the repo and I was able to make the proto-010- but I believe the order I did things in was wrong.